# Download .csv from an indirect Asana link

Tags: excel, vba, rest, web-scraping, asana-api

This code creates a download but not of the linked file as it is not direct. When I open the .csv file it downloads, it appears to be the data from the redirect, not the file linked to the redirect.

This is the code:

```
Sub Asana()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://app.asana.com/-/csv?id=955497629707333"

Dim HttpReq As Object
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
HttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
HttpReq.send


myURL = HttpReq.responseBody
If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStrm.Open
    oStrm.Type = 1
    oStrm.Write HttpReq.responseBody
    oStrm.SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "SER_Backlog_BRCC.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStrm.Close
End If

End Sub
```

It should be a spreadsheet copy of the data on the page, but it comes out with data in a spreadsheet of the website and not the linked .csv file you would get, if done manually.

[image: DOCHTML]

Should be this:

[image: should be this].

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have an authorization problem, as user/password is not supported by Asana.
You need a [Personal Access Token](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth#personal-access-token), which has to be set in your request header.

Please replace this line

```
'Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

and that line:

```
'HttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
HttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & "your Asana token here"
```

Comment: That did not work, it download the same DOCTYPEhtml file.

Comment: So you still have an authorization problem, as that is the result I also get, if I don't provide *any* Asana token. Maybe you should ask your question at https://forum.asana.com.